# Editing model with form.py

Tags: python, django

Can someone explain me the following? How can I update code, that I can use form on obj creating and editing (just one code)? Example

**model.py:**

```
class Car(models.Model):
    car = models.CharField('#', max_length=5)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return str(self.id)
```

**forms.py:**

```
class AddCar(forms.Form):
    car = forms.CharField(label='#', max_length=5, required=True, 
        widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class':'', 'title': '#', 
        'placeholder': '#', 'required': 'true'}))
```

**views.py:**

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def add_car(request):
    if request.method == 'POST': 
        form = AddCar(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            pass
    else:
        form = AddCar()
    return render(request, 'add_car.html', {'form': form, })
```

So, I need to create a new url

```
url(r'^edit/(?P<car_id>\d+)/$', 'cars.views.edit_car', name='edit_car'),
```

Then in **views**:

```
@csrf_protect
@login_required
def edit_car(request, car_id):
    car = get_object_or_404(Car, pk=car_id)
```

Whats next? How to use `AddCar` form with values from `car`? How to check, if user update the information in form?

Thanks.

**Update**

In `edit_car` I use ([docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/api/#django.forms.Form))

```
form = AddCar(car)
```

But I have an error: `'Car' object has no attribute 'get'` for all `{{ form.field }}` in template.

Answer (score 1):

The `car` can be passed to the `ModelForm` instance as the `instance` keyword argument, ie.

```
AddCar(instance=car)
```

To detect changes, you could use the `is_valid()` method of the `AddCar` instance combined with `cleaned_data` dictionary. You would have to fetch the `car` object as already you are, instantiate the `AddCar` form with `request.POST` values, and then compare values between the `car` you've fetched and `AddCar.cleaned_data`.

Comment: with `ModelForm` I cant use widgets, etc.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/#overriding-the-default-fields

Comment: I have more code, I dont have so much time to change it for modelform. Do you know another method to resolve the problem?

Comment: You could use `model_to_dict` (from [here](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/models.py#L106)) to construct a dictinary that would be then passed to the `initial` keyword argument to `AddCar` form.

Answer (score 1):

```
form = AddCar({'car': get_object_or_404(Car, pk=car_id,).name,})
```

Without `ModelForm`